# Difference between DKIM and DomainKeys

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, domainkeys, opendkim

There are two methods for signing mail out there (DKIM and DomainKeys). While some sources say that DomainKeys are "ancient", others say you need both, even though to my understanding they do almost the same.

- Do I need both methods applied to our mailserver?
- Does Google, Hotmail and co. check for both?

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia entries contain very good information on both and can help getting rid of your confusions:

[DomainKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)

> DomainKeys (informally DK) is a deprecated e-mail authentication
>   system designed by Yahoo[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) to verify the DNS domain of an e-mail
>   sender and the message integrity.
>
> Aspects of DomainKeys, along with parts of Identified Internet Mail,
>   were combined to create DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)[3][4]
>   which is now widely used.[5]
>
> Both DomainKeys and DKIM were published in May 2007, DomainKeys as an
>   "historical" protocol, and DKIM as its standards-track replacement.

[DomainKeys Identified Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)

> DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) is an email authentication method
>   designed to detect email spoofing by providing a mechanism to allow
>   receiving mail exchangers to check that incoming mail from a domain is
>   authorized by that domain's administrators.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) It is intended to
>   prevent forged sender addresses in emails, a technique often used in
>   phishing and email spam. DKIM allows the receiver to check that an
>   email claimed to come from a specific domain was indeed authorized by
>   the owner of that domain which is done using cryptographic
>   authentication.

[DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)

As you can see, DKIM is the current standard and was developed as a replacement for Domainkeys. So, you don't need both and having DKIM is enough.